# How to fix: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to get numpy array of mixed datatypes (int, float, string):

```
import numpy as np
l1=['car',10,4.5]
arr=np.array(l1, dtype='|S5, i4, f8')
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'car'
```

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import numpy as np

l1= [('car',10,4.5),('train',1000,5000)]
arr=np.array(l1, dtype='|S5,i4,f8')

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[('car',   10, 4.5e+00) ('train', 1000, 5.0e+03)]
```

You need to put each row inside the list as tuples so it works. For only car this works:

```
l1= [('car',10,4.5), ]
arr=np.array(l1, dtype='|S5,i4,f8')
```